# I am trying to run this simple program but I have this error message "expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘<’ token"

Tags: c

This is the full error message 
hw2.c:13: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘<’ token

This is the line in question

```
int main <void>
```

I can post more info if anyone needs it.

Comment: `<void>` is not valid C... Are you thinking C++, perhaps?

Comment: that was a last minute thing I added because I didn't know how to fix it.

Comment: Assuming you're just trying to create your main method, `int main()` should work just fine. You need the parentheses.

Comment: I can post the whole program if needed.

Comment: feel free, but if you're mixing C++ into C code, the rest of the program's likely to be riddled with similar syntax errors.

Comment: @MarcB: `int main <void>` isn't valid C++ either.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to create a main method?

```
int main(void){
    // lol code
}
```